# Karate gatling integration : Reports are not generated when using custom http client

Tags: karate

I am currently using karate framework with gatling integration(karate-gatling version is 0.8.0.1). When i use Apache Http client it generated the gatling reports for the api i am hitting. One of my api endpoint requires request to be signed(Oauth signing), So i can not use ApacheHttpClient for this api, that's why for this i am using following open source custom http client which provides request signing

https://github.com/gtnicol/karate-okhttp-signpost

When i use this client it does not generate the gatling report and throw following error

```
Generating reports...
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
  at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: There were no requests sent during the simulation, reports won't be generated
  at io.gatling.charts.report.ReportsGenerator.generateFor(ReportsGenerator.scala:48)
  at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.generateReports(RunResultProcessor.scala:76)
  at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.processRunResult(RunResultProcessor.scala:55)
  at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:68)
  at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:45)
  at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:37)
  at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
```

Please suggest how to generate gatling report while using the above client.
Note: I need request signing so i need this above client.

Answer (score 1):

First - you can easily get OAuth working with Karate, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth

Second - since only one API needs OAuth, you can use Java code for only that, and then pass any tokens back to all your other calls, and use Karate only.

And please note that even if you wanted to instrument the custom call in Gatling, you can do it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#custom

```
context.capturePerfEvent("myRpc-" + sleepTime, startTime, endTime);
```

Using a custom client is not supported in Karate, so please don't ask for it.

Comment: Thanks @Peter... But i am using the above custom client to make signed request and its working fine. In my case i require almost every request to be signed so the above open source project is using okhttp to achieve that. i just wanted to integrate gatling only so was able able to get the response back but while generating reports it was throwing the error.

Comment: @user3531900 I have nothing more to add to my answer above. I strongly recommend you implement the signing in Karate itself and I provided examples. there are some internal API-s involved which you may be missing since you went off on your own, so you have yourself to blame: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/http/HttpClient.java#L221